Integrate single beam sonar to VRX simulation
I'm developing a VRX based simulation environment and I'd like to include a fathometer/depth finder/single beam sonar to my simulation environment to provide awareness of the depth of operation.
I am aware of a multi-beam package, but not a single beam package. I'd love help employing this sensor information in my simulation.
